# Can not add Dynamics CRM to Registered Active Directory Application

Tags: asp.net-web-api, dynamics-crm, azure-active-directory

I am trying to create a SPA that uses Dynamics CRM Web API. While registering my Application in Azure Active Directory I can not find Dynamics CRM Online in the permissions to other applications window.

Do I need to upgrade my subscription or am I doing something wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easiest if your azure account uses the same login that has access to CRM. Then you will see CRM as an application option.

If the Azure account you're using isn't the same one that you use to login to CRM, you'll need to connect the two.  In order to do this, though, the O365 account you use for CRM needs to be a global admin in O365. [This page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/howto/setup-development-environment#bk_AssociateExistingAzureSubscription) has instructions.

> To associate an existing Azure subscription with your Office 365
>   account
>
> 1. Log on to the Microsoft Azure Management portal with your existing
>      Azure credentials (for example, your Microsoft ID such as
>      user@live.com).
> 2. Select the Active Directory node, then select the
>      Directory tab and, at the bottom of the screen, select New.
> 3. On the New
>      menu, select Active Directory > Directory > Custom Create.
> 4. In Add directory, in the Directory drop-down box, select Use existing
>      directory. Check I am ready to be signed out, and then select the
>      check mark in the lower-right corner. This brings you back to the
>      Azure Management Portal.
> 5. Log in with your Office 365 account
>      information. You will be prompted whether to use your directory with
>      Azure.
>
>    > Important To associate your Office 365 account with Azure AD,
>    >     you'll need an Office 365 business account with global administrator
>    >     privileges.
> 6. Select continue, and then Sign out now.
> 7. Close the browser and reopen the portal. Otherwise, you will get an access denied error.
> 8. Log on again with your existing Azure credentials (for example, your
>      Microsoft ID such as user@live.com). Navigate to the Active Directory
>      node and, under Directory, you should now see your Office 365 account
>      listed.

If your CRM O365 doesn't have global admin privileges, I would recommend just creating an azure account with the same account you use to connect to CRM According to [the SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt622431.aspx), "the account is free for application registration and your credit card won’t be charged if you only follow the procedures called out in this topic to register one or more apps."

Comment: No the azure and Dynamics CRM account are diffrent. I am doing this using free/trial version of dynamics and azure. I want anyone to be able to login to there dynamics CRM instance.